# Place random numbers in labels

Tags: c#, asp.net, random

I am creating a random number generator and I have 6 labels on screen each named num1, num2 etc.

When the user presses the randomise button the code called is

```
Random RanClass = new Random();
num1 = RandomClass.Next(1,6);
```

The error I am getting is saying you can not covert int to System.Web.UI.WebControlsLabel

How do I place the random numbers generated into the labels?

Comment: Don't instantiate a new Random() class each time the button is called. It will generate the same sequences. Make your RanClass static.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to set the [`Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label.text.aspx) property

```
num1.Text = RandomClass.Next(1,6).ToString();
```